# Passed react component is failing on accessibility unit test for form label?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, accessibility, babeljs

my reusable component looks like this `jsx

```
 return <div>
  <label className="label" htmlFor={name}>
  </label>
  <textarea
    name={name}
    aria-label={name}
    id={id || name}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    value={value}
  />
</div>;
```

and its being pulled in like this below inside another component like this

```
    <TxtareaComp
          name="Lorem"
          value={this.props.lorem}
          id="lorem-ipsum"
          onChange={this.props.lorem}
          />
```

and when its rendered it looks like this

```
<div><label class="label"  for="Lorem">Lorem</label>
<textarea name="lorem" " id="Lorem">
 </textarea>
  </div>
```

works perfectly fine, but the problem is the its failing tests for `accessibility`

Its saying I am missing a label

```
   Sniffybara::PageNotAccessibleError:
   Form elements must have labels

   Elements:
   <TxtareaComp...
   ["#lorem-ipsum"]
```

Although there is a label, how can i bypass to fix this... while using the existing component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` needs the **`id`**, not the name, of the `input`. So if you're setting the `id` via `id={id || name}` on the input, you need to set `htmlFor` the same way: `htmlFor={id || name}` on the label.

Of course, you have the other option: Putting the `input` *inside* the `label`. Then you don't need `for` or an `id` on the `input` (for this; you may need the `id` for something else). But whether you can do that depends on your styling.